# How to append a set of bullets in a jQuery drop down menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, warnings

I have been trying to append a set of items in a dropdown menu (see jQuery script below). Everything is working, however netbeans warns that "XHTML element "li" not allowed as child of xhtml script". Actually, I tried both $().html and $().append. The former works better since it clears the cache. Is there anyway to remove this warning? Is there any real problem behind this warning? I will really appreciate any hint.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>JQuery Examples</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  


        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            a{ text-decoration: none; color: rgb(255,255,255);}
            ul{ margin: -5px; list-style: none; font-size: 12px;}
            ul.dropdown{position: relative;}
            ul.dropdown li {  float: left;  background: #000066; zoom: 1; }
            ul.dropdown a:hover {background: #0f0; color: #00f; }
            ul.dropdown li a { display: block; padding: 4px 8px; border-right: 1px solid #000; }
            ul.dropdown ul { width: 200px; visibility: hidden; position: absolute;  }
            ul.dropdown ul li {background: #000066; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; float: none;}
            ul.dropdown ul li a { border-right: none; width: 100%; } 
            ul.dropdown ul ul { left: 100%; top: 0; }
            .hover {position: relative; }     
        </style>        

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("ul.dropdown li").hover(function() {
                    $(this).addClass("hover");
                    $('ul:first', this).css('visibility', 'visible');
                    $("#inbox").html("<li><a href=\"http://example.com\">Message1</a></li>");
 //                   $("#inbox").append("<li><a href=\"http://example.com\">Message2</a></li>");                    

                }, function() {
                    $(this).removeClass("hover");
                    $('ul:first', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
                });
                $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append("  >");
            });
        </script>



    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="http://example.com">Messages</a>
                <ul>
                    <li ><a href="http://example.com">Inbox</a>


                        <ul id="inbox">

                                                    <!-- The append should enter here! -->

                        </ul>


                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Sent box</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://example.com">.Net</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://example.com">JSP</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://example.com">Movies</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Movie 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Movie 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Movie 3</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://example.com">Actor 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://example.com">Actor 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://example.com">Actor 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Action Movies</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://example.com">Movie 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://example.com">Movie 5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Comedy Movies</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://example.com">Books</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Field 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Field 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://example.com">Love 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://example.com">Love 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Field 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Field 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com">Field 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>            
        </ul>
    </body>
```

Comment: can you show your generated html ?

Comment: Sure @MohammadAdil! See http://jsfiddle.net/DanielTheRocketMan/jACm7/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Ok I noticed I didn't answer your question.

The error that you are getting is because of the `XHTML`. XHTML has certain rules you have to follow. In the case of the error you are getting you need to change your `<script></script>` block to be like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.dropdown li").hover(function() {
      $(this).addClass("hover");
      $('ul:first', this).css('visibility', 'visible');
      $("#inbox").html("<li><a href=\"http://example.com\">Message1</a></li>");
      //$("#inbox").append("<li><a href=\"http://example.com\">Message2</a></li>");                    

      }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul:first', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
      });
    $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append("  >");
  });
//]]>
</script>
```

Notice the `//<![CDATA[` and its closing `//]]>` this tells the page not parse whatever is inside the CDATA as XML.

This is only important when you have inline `<script></script>`. This error does not happen when you have it as an external `.js` file.

Here is a good read on the matter: http://javascript.about.com/library/blxhtml.htm

---

There is no problem with your html appending.
I added the [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) method so that the submenu doesn't keep growing everytime you hover over it.

```
...
$('#inbox').empty()
    .append("<li><a href=\"http://example.com\">Message1</a></li>")
    .append("<li><a href=\"http://example.com\">Message2</a></li>");
...
```

**[DEMO WITH .APPEND()](http://jsfiddle.net/vCTPB/)**

if you want to still use the `.html()` this is how it would be used:

```
...
$('#inbox').html("<li><a href=\"http://example.com\">Message1</a></li>" +
    "<li><a href=\"http://example.com\">Message2</a></li>");
...
```

**[DEMO WITH .HTML()](http://jsfiddle.net/9aCJY/)**

Comment: thank u both for the answer and the document describing the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Don't append `>` (*as an arrow sign*) it'll make your html invalid, use `&gt;` instead or better use an icon

```
$("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append("  &gt;");
```

Demo `---->`  http://jsfiddle.net/jACm7/5/

---

While appending new html, try to use jquery instead of raw html

```
$("#inbox").html($("<li>").html($("<a>").prop('href', 'http://example.com').text('Message1')));
```

Demo `---->`  http://jsfiddle.net/jACm7/6/

Comment: Thank u @Mohammad-Adil. I learned something new, but the HTML warrning is in "                    $("#inbox").append("<li><a href=\"http://example.com\">Message2</a></li>");" or "                    $("#inbox").html("<li><a href=\"http://example.com\">Message1</a></li>");" about the "li" element!